# Updating Multiple Child Entities which has their own Child Entity with the Parent entity in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-3.0

The situation is like this:

Consignment has multiple consignmentLine entities, while consignmentLine has multiple consignmentDoc entities. I have to update all of them at the same time.

The Consignment Model:

```
namespace Test.Models
{
public partial class Consignment
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public bool? Deleted { get; set; }
    public bool? HasDangerousGoods { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReadyOn { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionToLeave { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ConsignmentDocument> ConsignmentDocument { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ConsignmentLine> ConsignmentLine { get; set; }
}
```

The ConsignmentLine Model:

```
namespace Test.Models
{
public partial class ConsignmentLine
{
    public ConsignmentLine()
    {
        ConsignmentDocument = new HashSet<ConsignmentDocument>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid? ConsignmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Consignment Consignment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ConsignmentDocument> ConsignmentDocument { get; set; }
}
```

The ConsignmentDocument Model:

```
namespace Test.Models
{
public partial class ConsignmentDocument
{
    public bool? Deleted { get; set; }
    public Guid? ConsignmentLineId { get; set; }
    public Guid? ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Consignment Consignment { get; set; }
    public virtual ConsignmentLine ConsignmentLine { get; set; }
    public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

My Current ConsignmentController Update Method:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutConsignment(Consignment consignment)
    {
        var existingcon = _context.Consignment
            .Include(cl => cl.ConsignmentLine)
            .Include(l => l.Legging)
            .Include(cd=> cd.ConsignmentDocument)
            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == consignment.Id);

        if (existingcon.Id != consignment.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        //update consignment
        _context.Entry(existingcon).CurrentValues.SetValues(consignment);

        //update or add consignmentLine
        foreach (var conline in consignment.ConsignmentLine)
        {
            var existingline = existingcon.ConsignmentLine
                .Where(x => x.Id == conline.Id)
                .SingleOrDefault();
            if (existingline != null)
            {
                _context.Entry(existingline).CurrentValues.SetValues(conline);
            }
            else
                existingcon.ConsignmentLine.Add(conline);

        }

        //remove consignmentline
        foreach (var line in existingcon.ConsignmentLine.ToList())
        {
            if(!consignment.ConsignmentLine.Any(x=> x.Id == line.Id))
            {
                _context.ConsignmentLine.Remove(line);
            }
        }

        //add or update Legging
        foreach (var newleg in consignment.Legging)
        {
            var leg = existingcon.Legging
                .Where(x => x.Id == newleg.Id)
                .SingleOrDefault();

            if (leg != null)
            {
                _context.Entry(leg).CurrentValues.SetValues(newleg);
            }
            else
                existingcon.Legging.Add(newleg);
        }

        //remove legs
        foreach (var leg in existingcon.Legging.ToList())
        {
            if(!consignment.Legging.Any(x=> x.Id == leg.Id))
            {
                _context.Legging.Remove(leg);
            }
        }

        //Add or edit consignmentDocument against Consignment
        foreach (var newdoc in consignment.ConsignmentDocument)
        {
            var doc = existingcon.ConsignmentDocument
                .Where(x => x.DocumentId == newdoc.DocumentId)
                .SingleOrDefault();

            if (doc != null)
            {
                _context.Entry(doc).CurrentValues.SetValues(newdoc);
            }
            else
                existingcon.ConsignmentDocument.Add(newdoc);
        }

        // Delete ConsignmentDocument against Consignment
        foreach (var doc in existingcon.ConsignmentDocument.ToList())
        {
            if (!consignment.ConsignmentDocument.Any(x => x.DocumentId == doc.DocumentId))
            {
                _context.ConsignmentDocument.Remove(doc);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ConsignmentExists(consignment.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Ok(consignment);
    }
```

I have done updating the consignmentLine entity update with Consignment, but how can I also update the consignmentDoc table along with consignmentLine?

Comment: Just a question to clarify, I noticed your Consignment model has a collection of ConsignmentLine and ConsignmentDoc, and then your ConsignmentLine has a collection of ConsignmentDoc as well. This represents an odd data relationship, can you please clarify how those are supposed to fit together?

Comment: The consignmentDoc is the join table of Consignment, ConsignmentLine and Documents table. Because the user can put document for consignment as well as for consignmentLine, while posting for consignment line the consignmentdoc table will store both the consignmentId and consignmentLineId, whereas if documents are posted against the consignment, it will only store the consignmentId for those documents.

Comment: Is the relationship between `Consignment` and `Document` many-to-many ? What's the `Document` model? Still not clear about the model relationship, you can refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) for more details about the relationship in EF Core.